# What happen if wrap a tag with navlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just like this

```
<NavLink>
    <a></a>
</NavLink>
```

Is it still SPA? OR MPA?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<NavLink>
    <a></a>
</NavLink>
```

This is MPA clearly.

However, if you wanna have SPA then,

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

<NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
```